# Generate a sequence of numbers for a certain interval in vertica

Tags: sql, vertica, generate-series

Generate a sequence of numbers for a certain interval.
In postgresql there is a function generate_series.
You need to write something similar to sql for vertica

| id | low_esn | high_esn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 10 | 13 |
| 102 | 5 | 7 |

There should be a result:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 10 |
| 101 | 11 |
| 101 | 12 |
| 101 | 13 |
| 102 | 5 |
| 102 | 6 |
| 102 | 7 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 way for it:

1. You can add extension for it:
   https://github.com/tensquaregames/Vertica-GenerateSeries-Extension
2. You can use answer from this question.
   [vertica generate table with numbers & select prime numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44994183/vertica-generate-table-with-numbers-select-prime-numbers)

I hope that these links help you.

Answer (score 0):

Vertica has the TIMESERIES clause for that, which is considerably more embedded into its SQL engine than the `generate_series` function of PostgreSQL.

TIMESERIES works on an already existing time series in the data - which can just consist of two rows.

We need to "verticalise" your horizontal representation of start and finish, then convert the integers to timestamps (with microseconds) - and I just do that in the `OVER(... ORDER BY)` sub-clause of the `TIMESERIES` clause - to generate a time series spaced by the interval supplied just after the `TIMESERIES` keyword, out of which we get back the microseconds again:

```
WITH
indata(           id , low_esn, high_esn) AS (
          SELECT 101 , 10     , 13
UNION ALL SELECT 102 ,  5     ,  7
)
,
-- the TIMESERIES clause needs an initial tuple and a final tuple
borders(id,val) AS (
  SELECT
    id
  , low_esn
  FROM indata
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    id
  , high_esn
  FROM indata
)
SELECT
  id
, MICROSECOND(ts) AS val
FROM borders
TIMESERIES ts AS '1 microsecond' OVER (
  PARTITION BY id
  ORDER BY TIMESTAMPADD(MICROSECOND,val,TIMESTAMP '2000-01-01'
)
);
```

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 10 |
| 101 | 11 |
| 101 | 12 |
| 101 | 13 |
| 102 | 5 |
| 102 | 6 |
| 102 | 7 |